# pass data between view controller using storyboard xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.1

i have many view controller in my storyboard some how i am passing my login page data email id to my third view controller but i am getting the NULL value

**here is my code for 1st view**

```
//in first view i already import my second view below code is in 1st view
//.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailid;

//.m
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sendemailid"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        UploadImageData *controller = (UploadImageData *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.newemailid = self.emailid.text;
        NSLog(@"emailid is %@",emailid.text);
    }


}
// i already created segue by identifier name "sendemailid"
```

**now in my second view**

```
// in .h 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *emailid;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *newemailid;

// .m in view didload method

self.emailid.text = self.newemailid;
    NSLog( @"we get the emailid %@", emailid.text );
```

i am getting null value and one more thing i am using NSUSER DEFAULT to save emailid in 1st view. i don`t able to know why value is not passing is that i am missing something please suggest...

Comment: try printing off the value of `controller.newemailid` in the first `UIViewController` (after `NSLog(@"emailid is %@",emailid.text);`)

Comment: i am not getting even my NSLOG method also actually i have another segue i want when my another segue is performed that time my emailid send to but i don`t want jump in that view controller i just want to send data for further use

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. If you did not get the `NSLog`, then that code is not running... Maybe you could try and re-state your question, explaining what is happening *now* and what you would *like* to happen

Answer (score 1):

I have done with this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sendemailid"])
    {
        UploadImageData *controller=segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.newemailid=self.emailid.text;
    }
}
```